# Publish Provider-Hosted App Problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, provider-hosted-app, token

I have a default provider-hosted application that prints the site title.

When I publish it to my Windows Azure it works great, but when I publish it to my company server (Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5) I got this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   on TestPHWeb.TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(String refreshToken, String targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm) on TestPHWeb.SharePointAcsContext.RenewAccessTokenIfNeeded(Tuple`2& accessToken, Func`1 tokenRenewalHandler) on TestPHWeb.SharePointAcsContext.GetAccessTokenString(Tuple`2& accessToken, Func`1 tokenRenewalHandler) on TestPHWeb.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

My code:

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
{
     clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
     Response.Write(clientContext.Web.Title);
}
```

I'm not using WebDeploy to publish it, I'm using 'File System' and copying files to my IIS folder.

It's a provider-hosted app for SharePoint Online written using VS2013

Someone knows what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question about this recently.

I believe that when the app is hosted in Azure/IIS that both sides of the protocol are in the cloud,

But when the app is hosted "on-prem", there is no easy way for both sides of the protocol to talk. But this case should be the same as running "localhost-hosted" where the local browser asks if you want to "trust localhost"?

Are you getting to this prompt? Does it ask you to trust your on-prem IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this for me by adding the `[SharePointContextFilter]` attribute to my action method where I was trying to create the spContext.

```
[SharePointContextFilter]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        Models.User user = GetUser();
        ViewBag.CurrentUser = user;
        var books = db.GetAllBooks();
        return View(books);
    }
```

Didn't have enough rep to add a comment so adding this as an answer here.